# SpringData Mongodb @Field sometime works, sometime not

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I'm have the following class (I omit getter/setter for the first attributes):

```
public class Customer {

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    private String nickname;

    private String type;

    @Field("bag_list")
    @DBRef
    private ArrayList<Checkout> bagList;

    public ArrayList<Checkout> getBagList() {
        return bagList;
    }

    public void setBagList(ArrayList<Checkout> bagList) {
        this.bagList = bagList;
    }
}
```

The document in MongoDb is (omitting as before the trivial attributes):

```
{

"bag_list" : [ 
        {
            "$ref" : "checkout",
            "$id" : ObjectId("541fe83bc026bb4901f5f90c")
        }
    ]

}
```

The above code just doesn't work and if I debug it I can see that the object Customer in memory has a null value for bagList even if in the DB the data exists.

If I change it to:

```
public class Customer {

        private String firstname;

        private String lastname;

        private String nickname;

        private String type;

        @Field("bag_list")
        @DBRef
        private ArrayList<Checkout> bag_list;

        public ArrayList<Checkout> getBagList() {
            return bag_list;
        }

        public void setBagList(ArrayList<Checkout> bagList) {
            this.bag_list = bagList;
        }
    }
```

It works correctly. It seems like the @Field value it's ignored.

I'm running Spring Framework 4.0.6, Spring Data MongoDb 1.6.0 and MongoDb driver 2.12.1.

Comment: This is expected to work but it seems there is an [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1058) in 1.6.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll watch it hoping in a quick resolution :)

Comment: hey @alexio-cassani there's already a [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/pull/227) just in case you want to give it a spin.